# upgrading angular cli latest 9.1.2 not found

Tags: angular-cli, angular9

```
➜  ~ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0/bin/ng -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@8.3.23 postinstall /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@8.3.23
updated 1 package in 11.835s
➜  ~ npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.2
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@9.1.2
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

upgrading angular cli latest 9.1.2 but it's not found. same with yarn as well

yarn package manager - adding cli specific version but it's not found.

```
yarn add @angular/cli@9.1.2 --save-dev
yarn add v1.9.4
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
Couldn't find any versions for "@angular/cli" that matches "9.1.2"
? Please choose a version of "@angular/cli" from this list: 

❯ 9.0.0-rc.10 
  9.0.0-rc.9 
  9.0.0-rc.8 
  9.0.0-rc.7 
  9.0.0-rc.6 
  9.0.0-rc.5 
  9.0.0-rc.4 
  9.0.0-rc.3 
  9.0.0-rc.2 
  9.0.0-rc.1 
  9.0.0-rc.0 
  9.0.0-next.19 
  9.0.0-next.18 
  9.0.0-next.17
```

Comment: Are you using some kind of corporate mirror of the repository? That version's definitely on the public repo: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/9.1.2

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you and looks like that's the case